# Защита исходного кода, без возможности восстановления

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт, которым хочется поделится в интернете, но не хочется чтобы кто-то лез в исходной код. Вопрос: Есть программа желательно подешевле, которую не можно будет раскодировать и не потеряет своей функциональности.

### Спасибо!

Comment: Делятся либо исходниками, либо сервисом. Расшифровать можно все, что угодно. Так что не стоит заморачиваться - достаточно подвергнуть код обычной обфускации - и никто в него уже не полезет - ибо реально будет быстрее написать что-то свое.

Comment: А что у движка Дле используется?

Comment: А зачем делиться кодом, который невозможно будет расшифровать?

Comment: Пример привожу, написал скрипт галереи, все что надо менять можно  в админке =)

Comment: @Равнодушный обычно в закодированные движки ставят защиту. Всё, что реализовано стандартными способами php взламывается на ура. Dle по моему что-то вроде смеси base64, strrev и других плюшек. Стоит пару раз заменить один правильный тег на eval и солнце начинает светить как в самый ясный день :-)

Comment: DLE использует обфускацию, вполне возможно, что по неким своим алгоритмам. Только им это не помогает - движок в открытом доступе регулярно обновляется...)

@lampa, я и не собирался спорить, что коммерческие приложения не надо шифровать. Но человек же хочет "поделиться", а не продавать. А бесплатные скрипты кодируют только в одном случае - когда тупо стесняются своего быдлокода.

Comment: @Равнодушный да я просто описал ситуацию :-) DLE реально использует то, что я написал в пред. комменте, копался же :-)

Comment: @lampa, это и называется "обфускация"... )

Comment: @Равнодушный я именно про алгоритм :-)

Comment: @Равнодушный, ошибаешся... Например первое что не хотелось смена копирайта, чтобы не могли убрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если вы боитесь за права вашего скрипта, то поставьте лицензию, зачем все усложнять, шифровать и при этом бесплатно его выставлять, по моему вы заморачиваетесь, извините, если обидел

Comment: А насчет лицензии можете поподробнее сказать?  Просто скажем так, не хочется, чтобы кто-то убирал копирайт и переделывал что-то.

Comment: Ну, поищите в интернете о лицензии на свой продукт, я в этом не разбираюсь по правде, но просто предложил как идею

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько вариантов.

1. Зашифровать в ZEND.
2. Обусфуцировать php функции.

Answer (score 1):

а не проще просто сжать код ?
тогда что бы его прочитать понадобиться стальные нервы и много времени)

Comment: Был такой вариант, но с помощью минипрограмки или notepada++ можно все примерно вернуть на свои места за минуты работы =)

Comment: эм, как?
если поставить пробелы то не проблема, но название переменных назад не вернешь..

Comment: @cyber_ua что мешает переименовать эти переменные?

Comment: ну так нужно знать для чего она, и пока переименуешь (если скрипт большой) потратишь очень много времени..

Comment: @cyber_ua В редакторах есть такая фича, как замена текста, если чо :-)

Comment: и как вы будете их заменять?
у вас есть не знакомый скрипт, и нужно переменным дать понятные имена, редактор не обладает ИИ и не может сам проанализировать скрипт и дать название переменным.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ioncube.com/ вам сюда. Однако всё, что шифруется, также и дешифруется. Например, китайцами по 5$ за файл :-)

Вам могу по скидочке решить вопрос :-)

Comment: К сожалению, видел много видео, как его взламывают....

Comment: @Node_pro последние версии более криптостойкие для взлома. Скажу так - за 2 года свою библиотеку расшифрованную так нигде и не увидел. Можно еще zend encoder заюзать, по последние версии дешифровались на ура. Сейчас не знаю как.

Comment: А сколько стоит кодер?

Comment: Как раньше, так и сейчас ~6к руб.

Comment: @lampa, то, что вы не нашли нигде раскодированной версии своей библиотечки не значит, что ее не удалось расшифровать никому. Может быть, она просто никому не нужна?)

Comment: Не расшифровали -- значит не смогли. А то, что и не пытались -- это уже другой вопрос. Привет от Неуловимого Джо.

Comment: @nolka да нет, раз сливали, то скорее всего и раскодировать пытались. А сливали не абы кто :-)

Comment: Видимо скачали, посмотрели, поняли что не нужно такое и слили. Слили в прямом виде. Нигде не вижу ссылки на шифрованный код, поэтому ничего нельзя утверждать.

Comment: @KoVadim вам всё равно будет не интересно :-) И вы видимо не поняли, о чем я написал в своем комментарии. Слили - т.е. через хостинг как-то умудрились пролезть. Я могу вам отдельно зашифровать парочку файлов, если уж так желаете покопаться.

Comment: ох уже эти хакеры:) ломают зашифрованные скрипты вдоль и в поперек.